# WPF repaint all

Tags: wpf

I have a custom MarkupExtension that provides Brushes to a lot of places in an application. It works well until I want to change the colors at runtime.

I do everything I should in order to begin providing different values to the UI.

I want to know is there a way to force a WPF application to redraw and reevaluate all markup extensions.

Answer (score 1):

A markup extension is essentially a value placeholder.  There is no way to know which property values were originally produced by a markup extension; once `ProvideValue()` is called, the result replaces the extension, and all knowledge of the extension is gone.

What you *could* do is have your custom markup extension(s) delegate to `DynamicResourceExtension` and produce an expression-based value that will update once the corresponding brush resource is replaced:

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
    var brushKey = /* resolve resource key for brush */;
    return new DynamicResourceExtension(brushKey).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
}
```